# php Mail_mime stopped working need suggestions

Tags: php, mail-mime

I have a site that the other week was sending email just fine. All of a sudden it stopped working. I have narrowed the problem down to creating a new Mail_mime() object. Every time I try to use this the php just stops and returns a blank page or just what was created in the previous lines before that. There are no errors at all. 
The code below is what I have in the pages. If I comment out either include I of course get an error when it get to creating the Mail_mime.
Any pointers, direction to look or suggestions on what to check or how to figure this out would be great. The host Tech support was a joke, especially considering I just wanted to know if they changed anything.

```
include('Mail.php');
include('Mail\mime.php');
$mime = new Mail_mime();
```

Thanks for any help, my head is about to explode trying to figure this out.

Comment: If there are no errors at all, then you should make them reappear with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Otherwise look into the `error.log`.

Comment: The server has obviously been compromised by House Harkonnen :-) I would do as Mario suggests and turn on error reporting. There is an error in one of you classes somewhere.

Comment: There has been nothing in the error.log with this, it does have other erros but using the E_ALL did work and it now shows me some errors to work with!!(I'll save that for another post) THANKS Mario! Although I did have a Harkonnen agent lurking in there also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that's odd with the only code you presented is:

```
include('Mail\mime.php');
```

That should be:

```
include('Mail/mime.php');
```

In any case. (Regardless of server. Yes forward slashes work on DOS/Windows too. So why not keep it portable.)

Comment: After getting the errors to show! The problem was, somehow, the path had changed to the php files. I have no idea how but was able to set it(properly with forward slashes...thanks for the info on that) and now works great. Thanks again for the help!!!